# Remove spaces before file extension with regex

Tags: regex, space

I'm very new to this regex things, I have had some help before and I have manage fix some of my regex problem but now I have a problem

With Total Commander you can change name with regex and I trying to rename every file I have that have one or more space before the file extension.

I just like to find every file that have a space before the file extension so I can remove it.

Comment: Try `\s(\.[^.]+)$` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Will there be other dots in your filenames, and if so do you want to preserve preceding spaces or replace them too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\s+(\.[^.]+)$
```

Replace with `$1`. Remove `+` if you want to match just 1 space. Keep `+` to remove all spaces before the extension.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR4aN1/1).

Comment: Thanks alot, yes it work, it even remove the file extension but that is ok. the all have .zip so I can easy add them after. Thanks

Comment: Actually, if you use `$1` in the replacement, the extensions will be restored after matching. See, `(...)`, not only matches, it also *captures* (stores in a buffer) the matched subtext. `$1` is a back-reference to that text.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this in linux

```
find 'path to folder' -type f  -regextype posix-awk -regex  '.*/.+ *[.][A-Za-z]{3}$' -exec rm -f  {} \;
```

`-type f` # find all files

`-regextype posix-awk -regex  '.*/.+ *[.][A-Za-z]{3}$'`  # use awk to match one more space followed by extension and remove them (be careful!)